# Send activation code by email after registration Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, email

Trying to set activation codes sending I've faced with following problem

```
ERROR 7020 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed;
nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 
Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8  
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials i15sm26828262wrb.91 - gsmtp ] with root cause
```

I've tried everything suggested about this issue: 2-Step Verification is turned off, Less Secure Apps are allowed and all additional properties added but nothing helped me. Could you, please, tell what's wrong.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myDB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=*password for DB*
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.freemarker.expose-request-attributes=true

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=mymail@gmail.com (100% correct - copypasted)
spring.mail.password=*password for mail* (also 100% correct)
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.protocol=smtps
mail.debug=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.auth=true
```

MailService

```
package com.example.myproject.service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class MailService {
private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

public MailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
}

@Value("${spring.mail.username}")
private String username;

public void send(String mailTo, String subject, String message){
    SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

    mailMessage.setFrom(username);
    mailMessage.setTo(mailTo);
    mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
    mailMessage.setText(message);

    javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
}
}
```

MailConfig

```
package com.example.myproject.config;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import java.util.Properties;
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {
@Value("${spring.mail.host}")
private String host;

@Value("${spring.mail.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.mail.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${spring.mail.port}")
private int port;

@Value("${spring.mail.protocol}")
private String protocol;

@Value("${mail.debug}")
private String debug;

@Bean
public JavaMailSender getMailSender(){
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost(host);
    mailSender.setPort(port);
    mailSender.setUsername(username);
    mailSender.setPassword(password);

    Properties properties = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", protocol);
    properties.setProperty("mail.debug", debug);
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    return mailSender;

}
}
```

Also I should notice that in MailService

```
private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

public MailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
}
```

I've got such message:

Could not autowire.
There is more than one bean of 'JavaMailSender' type.
Beans:
getMailSender   (MailConfig.java) mailSender   (MailSenderPropertiesConfiguration.class)

Comment: Assuming you are using SPring Boot you don't need the `MailConfig` as Spring Boot pre-configures that already based on the content of the `application.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

As exception messages says, Spring has more that 1 been "JavaMailSender" for inject.
It happened because you don't need to create JavaMailSender manually in your MailConfiig. Spring creates it based on property file.